# Protecting PayPal donation form from XSS - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, xss

I'm really paranoid about whether my donation form is safe from XSS or not (maybe I've been reading too many XSS articles). I've used the button generator provided by PayPal and inserted that into my page, but I also added a select element which has the 'item_name' value as its name attribute (one of PayPals html values):

i.e. like this:

```
<select name="item_name">
<option>...</option>
...
</select>
```

My first concern is whether that okay to do, because I'm storing the donate button in my account as a saved button, and PayPal says to put the code they give you "as-is" into your page, without alteration. I know its self evident, but its just a cheeky select element that'll make a better user experience :P. Is that okay?

Another question I want to ask is should I make the action attribute on the form that PayPal has given me point to a function in my controller which sanitizes the select elements value using htmlspecialchars() (is it even necessary to check the select element for such a purpose?), and in that function somehow point back to the PayPal url?

I don't have any other form on my website apart from an email me form, which I will apply XSS filtering to, but this PayPal form has got me confused as to how I need to protect it.

Comment: worse possible outcome is a user donates a different amount than attended (only if they fail to read once landed on pp site)- does not seem like an issue to me.

Comment: @Dagon What if that different amount is *more* than they wanted to give? I understand I should be happy with whatever the user gives me but I just want to make sure it's a smooth process with only me and them (and pp :P)

Comment: the amount would be clearly shown on the paypal page.

Comment: yeah your right, but not a good experience for the user (it could be a digit like 103904904 or something lol)

Comment: you are very luck to have so much free time if this is your only concern regarding your web site.

Comment: @Dagon I'll take that advice; I can be a pessimist at times

Comment: for all the news of site hacking, i have seen none of it on any of my sites since my first site was live in 1997

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not taking input from the client and displaying it on your website, you do not need to worry.

The two primary cases of XSS would be database and request based. In a database-based system, an attacker submits malicious code to a publicly displayed field (comment form, something along those lines). Then, whenever the data from this form is display, the code is run - assuming the database is not properly sanitized.

The other method would be XSS via a GET request. An attacker sends a victim a link to your site with malicious code as a parameter in the URL. If this parameter is displayed on the page and not properly sanitized, XSS can occur.

```
echo "You just bought a " . $_GET['itemname'];
```

You should not need to worry in your case, and don't bother sending to a controller to sanitize first - PayPal takes care of that themselves.

Additional note: You don't need to worry about XSS in your email form, Javascript is not run by mail clients. What you do need to worry about is [header injection](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/email-injection/).

Comment: The reason I'm worried is because of someone else kindly telling me to make sure your backend is secure because anybody can change the the PayPal form

Comment: Your donation button isn't going through your backend, though - it's going directly to PayPal. The worst someone could do is modify it to donate a different amount of money than what you have set it default, if any.

Comment: I haven't set any default amount, the user can decide how much to give, would that eliminate that possibility?

Comment: Thanks, I feel more comforted. Hopefully things will be okay. Thanks for the email security tip as well. (PS: love your website)

Comment: If you don't mind explaining, what is the echo statement supposed to illustrate?

Comment: The echo statement shows an example where a XSS could take place. To properly, you could do: `echo "You just bought a " . htmlspecialchars($_GET['itemname']);`, though note that this is a rather contrived example and not something you'd expect to see in production code.

Comment: I see; what would be suitable as production code? Having a class which filters such input and calling its functions? Thank you btw for imparting your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

PayPal form (html) can't be changed using XSS unless intruder gets access to your backend where you have option to change those HTML pages that are displaying PayPal form. But in this case the PayPal form is not what you should be worried about. 
By the way, it's OK to think like you did at this case, security is at first place.

Comment: What do you mean by "option to change those HTML pages that are displaying PayPal form"? Could you please explain

Comment: With this I meant that if you are using some kind of CMS (wordpress or custom made) which allows editing template (html,php,js) files/pages directly from browser.

Comment: Oh, I only use a separate header and footer, call those from my controller to display along with the main body i.e. $this->load->view('header', $data), $this->load->view('body'), etc. I echo out variables in the header such as changing the title dynamically etc